# PostgreSQL current_role, current_user execution context

Tags: postgresql

When calling a function or procedure in PostgreSQL, where the execution context is SECURITY DEFINER, the calls to current_user and current_role return the value of the definer and not the value of the current user logged in (or set role).

Take for example the following scenario ...

```
postgres=# select current_role, current_user;
 current_role | current_user 
--------------+--------------
 postgres     | postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# create schema test;
CREATE SCHEMA

postgres=# grant usage on schema test to public;
GRANT

postgres=# create user testproxy login password 'Password00';
CREATE ROLE

postgres=# create user testuser login password 'Password00';
CREATE ROLE

postgres=# grant testuser to testproxy;
GRANT ROLE

postgres=# create or replace function test.the_role() returns varchar as $$
postgres$# begin
postgres$#     return current_role::text;
postgres$# end; $$ language plpgsql security definer set search_path = test, pg_temp, pg_catalog;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=# create or replace function test.the_user() returns varchar as $$
postgres$# begin
postgres$#     return current_user::text;
postgres$# end; $$ language plpgsql security definer set search_path = test, pg_temp, pg_catalog;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=# grant execute on function test.the_role() to public;
GRANT
postgres=# grant execute on function test.the_user() to public;
GRANT
```

Now we log into the database using the `testproxy` account, to run the test ...

```
postgres=> select current_role::text, current_user::text;
 current_role | current_user 
--------------+--------------
 testproxy    | testproxy

postgres=> set role testuser;
SET

postgres=> select current_role::text, current_user::text;
 current_role | current_user 
--------------+--------------
 testuser     | testuser
(1 row)

postgres=> select test.the_role(), test.the_user();
 the_role | the_user 
----------+----------
 postgres | postgres
(1 row)
```

As you can see the direct calls to current_role and current_user are working fine, but when called within another function they return the function owner, not the logged in user. If I change to use SECURITY INVOKER, my understand is it will the return the logged in user.

But here's the issue, I need it to be SECURITY DEFINER because the user may not have access to the underlying calls or objects, yet I still need it to return the logged in user!

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I can understand why you would want that for the **user** but not for the **role**. The point of roles is to embed the privileges you have on the database; in the middle of the function execution, it corresponds to the definer of the function. Can you please explain the need for role to behave the way you describe?

Comment: For example in the middle of the function I need to know who the user is, to get say preferences or data associated with the logged in user. The user themselves will not have access to the table, as it's queried only from the function.

Or suppose the functio needs to get a list of the roles the ```set role ...``` enables. I can think of a ton of reasons a function or a procedure may need to determine who called it at runtime.

Comment: Firstly, this does not answer my question. I asked in what context it makes sense for role to behave the way you describe, **as opposed to user**; I even formatted the text in bold font to make the point clear but you give me an answer about user... That was not the problematic part I was asking details about. Secondly, to cover what you are describing, why not pass `current_user` as a parameter of your function? Which you could call from another function with `SECURITY INVOKER` set for it.

Comment: I also do not see why either of your scenarios would need a `SECURITY DEFINER` function... You would not prevent a user from reading their own preferences from a table. Instead, you would define a RLS policy so that users can read only their preference and nobody else's. For role inheritance, every user has access to know (at least) all the roles they were granted. Again, no need for a `SECURITY DEFINER` function there.

Comment: In conclusion: your question seems to be an example of [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): whatever you want to do, you *think* you are on the right path and you just need some details to complete your attempted solution when in fact, you are most likely getting farther away from the real solution you are looking for. I recommend you edit your question to describe your actual goal. Oh! and it is not the solution to whatever problem you have but for the record, there is a `session_user` global variable that behaves the way you are looking for (but not `session_role`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear problem statement in your question, but if I read between the lines, I guess that you would like to have a function that returns the authenticated user, no matter under what security context you are currently running.

You can get the authenticated user with

```
SELECT session_user;
```